# Is the derivative operator Hadamard differentiable?

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives

Is the derivative operator $f\mapsto f'$ [Hadamard differentiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_derivative)? If so, under which conditions (does the derivative need to be bounded maybe?). I searched for references but cannot find anything. I would love a step-by-step proof that I could study.

Comment: Have you tried just applying the definition? That's all you need here...

Comment: I think that my problem is actually I don't understand some basic concepts of banach spaces and functional analysis, so wrapping my neck around the definition is difficult for me. However I could not say what exactly it is I don't understand (otherwise I would ask question on that). I was hoping that working through some simple examples would help me understand the definition better.

Comment: To the person who gave a downvote: you are right. My question does not show much effort by myself. I should have give my attempt even if I'm stuck. My goal was actually to prove that integration is hadamard differentiable. I thought by studying proof for derivative case it would be useful exercise to adapt to integration case. However it seems that was not a good plan since integration operator is also linear so I guess it is the same proof. in any case, I apologize for the poorness of my question and I will improve.

Comment: Here there's no need to understand the definition in a deep way - it's clear that $(D(f+hg)-Df)/h=Dg$. (If you consider that the point to a derivative is to approximate functions by affine functions, it seems pretty plausible that a _linear_ map should be differentiable...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich that makes sense. I have no experience with directional derivatives so it is still difficult for me just the concept that the derivative is itself a function. Studying your answer that doesn't seem to matter, but it still makes it difficult for me to understand definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not well defined; to make sense of it you need to specify two Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$ such that $f'\in Y$ for every $f\in  X$. Having done that you can then ask about differentiability of $D:X\to Y$.

Once you do that it seems the answer must be yes, just because $D$ is linear: If $f,g\in X$ and $h$ is a non-zero scalar then $$\frac{D(f+hg)-D(f)}{h}=Dg$$and $Dg\to Dg$ as $h\to0$.